# Постоянно отображать маску при вводе номера телефона

Tags: javascript, css

Есть такой скрипт, работает отлично, только при вводе не отображается маска телефона `+7 (___) ___ ____`:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let callFormTel = document.querySelectorAll(".js-phoneMask")

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(callFormTel, function(input) {
    let keyCode

    function mask(event) {
      event.keyCode && (keyCode = event.keyCode)
      let pos = this.selectionStart
      if (pos < 3) event.preventDefault()
      let matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
        i = 0,
        def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
        val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ""),
        new_value = matrix.replace(/[_\d]/g, function(a) {
          return i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) || def.charAt(i) : a
        })
      i = new_value.indexOf("_")
      if (i !== -1) {
        i < 5 && (i = 3)
        new_value = new_value.slice(0, i)
      }
      let reg = matrix.substr(0, this.value.length).replace(/_+/g,
        function(a) {
          return "\\d{1," + a.length + "}"
        }).replace(/[+()]/g, "\\$&")
      reg = new RegExp("^" + reg + "$")
      if (!reg.test(this.value) || this.value.length < 5 || keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) this.value = new_value
      if (event.type === "blur" && this.value.length < 5) this.value = ""
    }

    input.addEventListener("input", mask, false)
    input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false)
    input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false)
    input.addEventListener("keydown", mask, false)
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrapper > input {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 4px;
}

.wrapper > .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  padding: 7px;
  z-index: -1;
}


// сделать невидимым "+7"

.placeholder span:first-of-type {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" class="js-phoneMask" autocomplete="off" required>
  <span class="placeholder"><span>+7 </span><span>(___) </span>___<span> ____</span></span>
<div>
```

Comment: Вроде работает ваш код. [Вот, что я вижу.](https://yadi.sk/i/loDPdc1Hr_ZClw) И это вполне подходит под маску *+7 (___) ___ ____* Она начинает отображаться, когда в поле достаточно цифр. Или это и есть ваша проблема?

Comment: при клике появляется маска исчезает, а надо что бы постоянно было +7 (___) ___ ____

Comment: @Alexander не нужно копировать **код предложенного решения** в свой вопрос, Вы тем самым делаете ответ на него неактуальным

Answer (score 5):

Один из вариантов решения данной задачи это сделать обертку для `input`, указав для нее относительную позицию и добавить еще один элемент, который будет размещаться поверх данного input'a и отображать требуемый `placeholder`.

Быстрый набросок что бы передать основную идею:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let callFormTel = document.querySelectorAll(".js-phoneMask")

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(callFormTel, function(input) {
    let keyCode

    function mask(event) {
      event.keyCode && (keyCode = event.keyCode)
      let pos = this.selectionStart
      if (pos < 3) event.preventDefault()
      let matrix = "+7 (___) ___ ____",
        i = 0,
        def = matrix.replace(/\D/g, ""),
        val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ""),
        new_value = matrix.replace(/[_\d]/g, function(a) {
          return i < val.length ? val.charAt(i++) || def.charAt(i) : a
        })
      i = new_value.indexOf("_")
      if (i !== -1) {
        i < 5 && (i = 3)
        new_value = new_value.slice(0, i)
      }
      let reg = matrix.substr(0, this.value.length).replace(/_+/g,
        function(a) {
          return "\\d{1," + a.length + "}"
        }).replace(/[+()]/g, "\\$&")
      reg = new RegExp("^" + reg + "$")
      if (!reg.test(this.value) || this.value.length < 5 || keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58) this.value = new_value
      if (event.type === "blur" && this.value.length < 5) this.value = ""
    }

    input.addEventListener("input", mask, false)
    input.addEventListener("focus", mask, false)
    input.addEventListener("blur", mask, false)
    input.addEventListener("keydown", mask, false)
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wrapper > input {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 4px;
}

.wrapper > .placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  padding: 7px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" class="js-phoneMask" autocomplete="off" required>
  <span class="placeholder"><span>+7 </span><span>(___) </span>___<span> ____</span></span>
<div>
```

Так же можно отключать видимость span'ов внутри класса `.placeholder` по достижению заполнения каждого из фрагментов:

```
// сделать невидимым "+7"

.placeholder span:first-of-type {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: к сожалению не то, видно задача не выполнима, так как я лично перерыл много ресурсов, но ответа так и не нашел. Есть тяжелый плагин jQuery inputmask, но он тяжелы.

Comment: при вводе цифр, маска остается в виде серой подложки под уже вбитыми цифрами.
Согласен, что ничего невыполнимого нет, это делается через плагин вездесущего jQuery...

Comment: @Alexander я же уже частично реализовал решение этого момента в своем примере. Вам только осталось добавить это в скрипт. Вы набираете часть номера и часть подложки выключается.