# Как сделать форму для введения телефона вида +7 (___) ___-____ на JS или JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка

Приветствуются ссылки , почитаю и сам сделаю. Разжевывать не надо.Скрин примера ниже

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9VQv.png

Ссылка на сайт с такой формой:https://vykup-nedvigimosti.ru/

Comment: Вроде недавно был вопрос про маску. Там проблема другая, но может помочь. [Link to question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1157269/384202)

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж в заголовке ответа "на jQuery" присутствует, то поспешу дать ссылку на довольно популярный плагин "jQuery Mask Plugin"

https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin

Если же использовать jQuery не хочется, то вот Вам на нативном js:
https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs